# Calculate average number of turns in a game

Tags: probability, expected-value

There are initially $1$ copper coin and $99$ gold coins in a box. Two players play the game. In each turn player randomly picks the coin first in his left hand, then randomly picks the coin in his right hand from the box. If it's the first player, then he changes the type of coin in left hand to the type of the coin in the right hand. Second player does the same, but vice versa. The goal of the first player is to make all the coins copper, and the second - gold. *What is the average number of turns in the game?* What I was able to do:

**Observation 1**
There are always $k$ copper and $(100-k)$ gold coins in the box

**Observation 2**
Do not consider whos turn it is. The change of hands has zero impact

Thus, we can introduce the system of equations. Let $E_n$ - be the number of average turns in the game, if there are $n$ copper and $(100 - n)$ gold coins in the box. Then:
$$ E_n = (1 - \frac{n}{100}) \cdot \frac{n}{99} \cdot E_{n+1} + \frac{n}{100} \cdot \frac{100-n}{99} \cdot E_{n-1} + \bigg( \frac{n \cdot (n-1)}{100 \cdot 99} + \frac{(100-n) \cdot (99 - n)}{100 \cdot 99} \bigg) \cdot E_n $$
$$ E_0 = 0 $$
$$ E_{100} = 0 $$
$$ E_1 - \text{is the answer} $$

I wasn't able to make any further progress. Well the system can be solved by writing some simple solver in any language, but I'm interested in paper solution

Comment: If you have the answer of $E_n$ numerically for arbitrary $n$ and total number of coins $N$, do you have a hypothesis for the analytic solution? Something you see from graphing.